# What is the difference in "yum search" and "yum search all"?

Tags: yum

What is the difference in "yum search" and "yum search all"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual page:

> search This is used to find packages when you know something about the package but aren't sure of it's name. By default search will try searching just  package  names  and  summaries,  but  if  that "fails" it will then try descriptions and url.
>
> Yum search orders the results so that those packages matching more terms will appear first.
>
> You can force searching everything by specifying "all" as the first argument.

Normally yum searches in

- the name
- the summary

With `search all` you can force searching in all the fields (e.g., in the description too)